# Installing Ubuntu, help with partitions

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

How to install Ubuntu on my vista based laptop? The copy of vista has ceased to boot, but I would still like to install Ubuntu without overwriting it if possible.

[image: Screenshot]

/Dev/sda3 windows vista loader (screen shot missed it)

Comment: hi i m new to linux ubuntu .i want to install ubuntu 14.04 with windows (dual boot) i have made one partition of 20 gb on my windows 7 to install ubuntu on this partition . After usb boot installation i m confused how to use this partition in "somthing else" step.
thank you

Answer (score 0):

0 Back up all your data by booting from a [LiveUSB](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/) and copy the data (on sda3 under /Users/YourName/ ) you want to preserve to an external HDD or USB flash drive

1 Install with an Ubuntu LiveUSB, following the [official Ubuntu install directions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall)

2 In the Installation Type screen of the installation you started in (2) above, choose the first option `Install Ubuntu alongside them.` Ubuntu's installer will guide you through resizing the partitions; sda3 is the one you should resize to make room for the root and the swap partitions.

Comment: i can only chose, something else?

Comment: - If you want to manually setup your partitioning scheme, , select the Something else option. You will find further advice on the DiskSpace page.  i have clicked the link but it is to advanced for my computor skills